# C# Calling a method

Tags: c#, methods

I have a form with multiple instances of a user control on it.

I've assigned the following:

```
Switch.armySwitchCloseButton.Click += armySwitchClose;
```

So when one of those instances is pressed, I call the following method:

```
void armySwitchClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The above method has a bunch of additional code in it which isn't required for here.

Now what I need to do is from another button, call this above function from every instance.

How can I do this?

Many Thanks

Comment: So you just like to execute the `armySwitchClose` function if a click on one of your usercontrols happens?

Comment: The usercontrol contains three buttons. Its the close button I'm trying to mimic.

If I click on the close button it will run a function that closes a tabpage in a tabcontrol

Comment: okay every close button shoud execute this method? How are the close buttons created? Do you create them at rumtime?

Comment: Usercontrols are created at runtime, The close button isn't displayed initially. its only displayed if it's relative tabpage is added.

Usercontrol buttons are:
armySwitchAddButton
armySwitchCloseButton
armySwitchSelectButton

Comment: Like `Switch1.armySwitchCloseButton.Click += armySwitchClose; Switch2.armySwitchCloseButton.Click += armySwitchClose; Switch3.armySwitchCloseButton.Click += armySwitchClose;` ?

Comment: Yea I have this in my form:

`Switch.armySwitchCloseButton.Click += armySwitchClose;`

`Switch.armySwitchAddButton.Click += armySwitchAdd;`

`Switch.armySwitchSelectButton.Click += armySwitchSelect;`

Comment: Do you have 3 times `Switch.armySwitchAddButton` or `Switch1.armySwitchAddButton`, `Switch2.armySwitchAddButton`, `Switch3.armySwitchAddButton`

Comment: You seem to be calling it for the same switch all the time. My code uses Switch1, Switch2, Switch3. Note `Switch` must not be a type but the instance variable and `armySwitchCloseButton` must not  be static. If `armySwitchAddButton` is static, you will always only one instance.

Comment: I don't refer to the instances of the usercontrol as in switch1 etc.

But to the usercontrol itself, which is called switch

Comment: So for example: armySwitch.cs > armySwitch > (armySwitchAddButton, armySwitchCloseButton, armySwitchSelectButton)

Answer (score 0):

In constructor of each user control you can pass the same instance of some object who knows how to run this method
    void armySwitchClose(object sender, EventArgs e)

Then, you call this method inside each event method, for ex:

```
Public Class UserControl(){
    private MakeEvent makeEvent;
    Public MyClass(MakeEvent makeEvent)
    {
        this.makeEvent = makeEvent;
        Switch.armySwitchCloseButton.Click += armySwitchClose;
    }

    void armySwitchClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        makeEvent.armySwitchClose(sender,e);
    }
}

Public Class MakeEvent() {

    void armySwitchClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //the real implementation
    }
}
```

Hope this solve your problem.

---

Oh, I think I get your problem wrong... When you click in one button all the other events in others UC must be triggered, right? This problem can be solved with the Observer Pattern

```
Public Interface IObserver
{
    void armySwitchClose(object sender, EventArgs e);
}

Public UserControl1: Observer
{
    void armySwitchClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //implementation UC1
    }
}

Public UserControl2: Observer
{
    void armySwitchClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //implementation UC2
    }
}
```

In button UC:

```
Public UserControlButton
{
    private List<IObserver> observers;
    public void addObserver(IObserver observer)
    {
        observers.Add(observer);
    }
    public void button_clickedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(IObserver observer in observers)
        {
            observer.armySwitchClose(object sender, EventArgs e);
        }
    }
}
```

In form with all buttons you call addObserver adding each user control.